# Getting stuck in a git rebase loop

Tags: git

I have two branches, `newfeature` and `release`. I work with a team so I need to pull from `release` every so often to get updates. To do this, I run a `git pull origin release` from my local `newfeature` branch. From here I resolve merge conflicts in VSCode by choosing either `current` or `incoming` changes. This is using the `rebase` process.

Upon finishing this process I run a `git push origin newfeature`. When I do this it says I need to pull the latest since there are conflicts. I run a `git pull origin newfeature` to get the latest and resolve conflicts. When I finish up the `rebase` , I finally am able to push to `origin/newfeature` to make sure it's up to date.

To double check that both branches are compatible, I run another `git pull origin release` to make sure all conflicts are resolved. Unfortunately, it says that there are conflicts and I have to repeate the process again. To avoid this issue, I've been pulling `release` and using `git push origin newfeature --force` to make sure it's up to date. I've read that using `--force` is not recommended since git is trying to tell me that there are conflicts.

My question is, how do I get out of this rebase loop?

Comment: I recommend doing `git fetch` instead of `git pull origin release`. This allows you to view the changes on the remote branch before trying to merge.

Comment: When you say "this is using the rebase process", what do you mean? `git pull origin release` does NOT rebase. `git pull` is an alias for `git fetch` and then `git merge`. If you resolve conflicts at the time of `git pull`, then do a `git rebase`, you will have to resolve those conflicts again. What are the full series of commands you use? Are you doing `git pull` followed by `git rebase`?

Comment: I think I am using the rebase process since it shows this line when I do a `git pull` 
`hint: Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
hint: "git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
hint: You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
hint: To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
`

Comment: Ok, I see. I think you have configured your `git pull` command to work differently than the default so that it rebases automatically instead of merging. Personally, I'm not a fan of this. I prefer doing `git fetch` and `git rebase` separately. In fact, I've read recommendations to avoid `git pull` entirely and use `git fetch` instead. Then you can deliberately choose `git merge` or `git rebase` yourself.

Comment: Will you update your question with a complete session of the commands and output you get from the command line?

Comment: And what is the output of `git config --get-regexp ^alias`?

Comment: After rebase, you cannot push to your branch again, because you have rewritten history. The only way out is to force-push (or merge, not rebase)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TLDR

After you rebase, you must force push your branch. You cannot do a normal push. Trying to do so is the root cause of your problem.

### Original longer answer with some assumptions

It sounds like you are following these steps:

1. `git checkout newfeature`
2. `git pull origin release`
3. Resolve conflicts
4. `git rebase release`
5. Resolve conflicts again
6. `git push origin`
7. Gives an error that you need to pull

Let's clarify what is going on here.

`git pull` is essentially `git fetch` followed by `git merge`. This is why you have to resolve conflicts. This is a standard part of merging the primary branch into a feature branch.

This by itself is sufficient. You can immediately do a `git push` and carry on with your day.

This creates a somewhat messy history tree with periodic merge commits. So some developers like to use `git rebase` to keep their changes in a linear history for each feature. And some projects will require this, especially when contributing to open source projects.

The key here is **DO NOT COMBINE A `git pull` AND A `git rebase`**. Do one or the other, but never both.

The correct way to rebase is like this:

```
git checkout newfeature
git fetch
git rebase origin/release
```

Then resolve conflicts for each commit as they are rebased. Notice that I use the `origin/release` remote tracking branch rather than the local `release` branch. This ensures that the rebase is on top of all of the work that has been merged into the remote release branch.

Note that a rebase will rewrite your feature branch history. So now you have to do `git push -f`. If you do `git push` after a rebase, then you will get the error message that is leading you to this infinite rebase loop.

You are right that you must be cautious about using `git push -f`. This is because you are now introducing an alternative history for your branch. If any of your teammates are working on the same branch with the old history, then they will encounter merge conflicts the next time they try to push their work to the central repo.

On the other hand, if you are the only person on this project or if you are sure that none of your teammates have pulled this branch, then you can safely force push. Also if you communicate with your teammates about your desire to force push, they can mitigate any problems on their side.

Answer (score 2):

`git rebase` is an action that changes the history of commits on the branch you are working on. When you work with a local branch which tracks a remote branch, this generally means that you will need to force push to update the remote branch.

Your workflow should probably be :

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
# fix conflicts if any
# test the resulting branch

git push --force-with-lease origin newfeature
```